# Reading multiple files in directory in C++

Tags: c++, file-io

Hi I am new to c++ and was wondering if we could read from multiple files all saved in a single directory. Basically I have a folder consisting of a number of text files and I want my program to read the files. The thing is the folder can be updated (new files added or existing files deleted) so cannot specify in the program the number of and name of files to read (I want to read all the files). So is there a way to do this?

Comment: try to google your title

Comment: The C++ standard does not deal with directories. This may change in a future version of the standard. Meanwhile you need to use either an OS-specific API (look up readdir) or a third party library such as boost::filesystem.

Comment: If you don't know the file names, how will you know which ones to read? Do you mean read *all* files in a given directory?

Comment: Yes we can definitely do that.

Comment: to beta yes i want to read all files in the directory

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
void run_with(const char* filename) {
std::ifstream fi(filename);
std::string s;
fi >> s;
std::cout << filename << " : " << s << std::endl;
}
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
 for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
  run_with(argv[i]);
}
```

Here you go. Its bassically opening one file but you open it multiple times.

Comment: Your answer doesn't seem to match what the OP is asking. Also, as is, your code won't compile.

Comment: what should be this?